# Populate model with JSON data in Angular

Tags: json, angular, object

I have a class with a model like this:

```
model = new questions(
                      1,                       // Id
                      '',                      // Name
                      '',                      // LastName
                      'undefined',             // Gender
                      'undefined',             // Filling Status
                      ...
)
```

The I have a service that makes a `GET` request to an API, and the response is like this:

```
{
"id": "5b6f",
"name": "John",
"lastName": "Doe",
"gender": "Male",
"fillingStatus": "Single",
 ...
}
```

How can I populate the model with this response, should I iterate to the object?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what's the class look like? in your example it looks like you're showing us an instance of a 'questions' class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular have a very good tutorial on this exact theme.

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

This uses reactive forms.

If you are not familiar with reactive forms you might want to do these tutorials first:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Basically, in the dynamic form tutorial, an HTTP request is made to the server to get form data using a service.

(the tutorial actually uses hardcoded data in a service but it is easy to swap this out for an HTTP request)

Once the data is retrieved it used to dynamically generate a reactive form.

The questions are then iterated to render the view and to render suitable form controls. The view hooks into the reactive form. You won't find a better tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Use the spread operator like this:

```js
let json = {
"id": "5b6f",
"name": "John",
"lastName": "Doe",
"gender": "Male",
"fillingStatus": "Single",
}

const model = {...json}

console.log(model);
```

Keep in mind that this is new syntax and not all browsers might support this syntax. So it is smart to transpile this code to ES5 syntax using babel.